# Calculate Date Linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, date

I have a Linq Query here that gives me data. I would then have to send this data by email as a reminder. I need two data calculations:

**Calculation1**: Date1 + 6 months, but I have to send the reminder 1 month before it expires.

Comment: these date methods may not be suported by ef.

Comment: Is it just `DateTime.Today.AddMonths(5)` and `date.AddDays(-6*7)`?

Comment: hm I don't get it...

Comment: Do you have two different date fields or single field. And do you need to send two different emails? Please elaborate your situation more so that people can provide suggestions easily. @IvayloS

Comment: Tip: If EF cannot handle "AddMonths", then precalculate that moment into a separate variable and use that variable in the query

Comment: To this example is one Date and one email. I have to do it somewhere else right away, so I wrote it here as well.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: Just use `Date1.AddMonths(6)` for 6 months and `Date1.AddMonths(5)` for the reminder
Question 2: Just use `Date2.AddDays(-42)` or `Date2.AddDays(-6*7)`

I leave here the link to official documentation for the list of all operations on dates: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0#methods

Comment: p.Date1 >= DateTime.Today 
                           && p.Date1 <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-42) what is the result?

Comment: I think it is true if p.Date is between this date and 42 days ago

Comment: I see that you are a new member, so i suggest you to upvote comment and answers that are useful or answer your question